# Window to fit title html/js

Tags: javascript, html, window, width, title

Is there any way of displaying a popup window of a webpage so that the width of the would always be chosen in such a way to fit the title of the window?

The window would always be popped with js function `window.open`

Comment: I didn't think you had control over this sort of thing because sneaky people hide windows offscreen.

Comment: Do you have access to the popup source? You could pass a URL parameter.

Comment: Yes, I do have access. I also have access to the title and the width. I just don't know how to set the width so that it fits the title